# (New to Rails) rails server error: cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have installed my JS runtime as Node, and I have bundle update-ed and bundle install-ed, but I still get this error:

```
/Users/macbook/Documents/Studies/Coding/the_back_end/the_odin_project/odin_on_rails/hello_app/config/boot.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)
    from /Users/macbook/Documents/Studies/Coding/the_back_end/the_odin_project/odin_on_rails/hello_app/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/macbook/Documents/Studies/Coding/the_back_end/the_odin_project/odin_on_rails/hello_app/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/macbook/Documents/Studies/Coding/the_back_end/the_odin_project/odin_on_rails/hello_app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/macbook/Documents/Studies/Coding/the_back_end/the_odin_project/odin_on_rails/hello_app/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    from /Users/macbook/Documents/Studies/Coding/the_back_end/the_odin_project/odin_on_rails/hello_app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Here's what's in my Gemfile ,

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.1.4'
gem 'puma',         '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.7.0'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I feel a little lost on that one, and I can't find any helpful answer anywhere.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have an issue with the gem `bootsnap` which main job is to accelerate rails startup time.

So, you should either :

- In case you want `bootsnap`, add `gem 'bootsnap'` to your gemfile to install it.
- In case you don't want `bootsnap`, remove the line `require 'bootsnap/setup'` in `config/boot.rb`

More info about `bootsnap` : https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap#how-does-this-work

Comment: I just did that, but then this other error appeared, /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:81:in `load_defaults': Unknown version "5.2" (RuntimeError)

Comment: I think you messed up with your `Gemfile`, because all your apps files seems to be from 5.2 version of rails while your `Gemfile` have  `gem 'rails', '5.1.4'`, you can try replacing it by `gem 'rails', '~> 5.2'` and launching an `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache on tmp.

tmp > bootsnap -> delete all the files.

[image]