# bootsnap `require': cannot load such file -- faraday/request/multipart (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bootsnap

Suddenly got this error when starting my rails server

```
bundle exec rails s
```

Here is the error message

```
         1: from /Users/michelleroos/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:15:in `require'
/Users/michelleroos/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:15:in `require': cannot load such file -- faraday/request/multipart (LoadError)
```

I'm not sure if it is something to do with my gem file. I Googled the error and tried the solutions proposed in other SO threads but nothing worked.

What I tried already:

- Basically everything in [this](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/73) thread
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493625/new-to-rails-rails-server-error-cannot-load-such-file-bootsnap-setup-load) thread
- And [this](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/302) thread

Here is my gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.3'

gem 'google-apis-sheets_v4'
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'dotenv-rails'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2' #5.2.3
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1', require: false #1.1.0
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'serialize_json-rails'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails' 
  gem 'factory_bot_rails' 
  gem 'rails-controller-testing' 

  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'faker' 
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: I'm encounting the absolut same message. Updated my ruby version to 3.2.2 but still there...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error after fixing an initial error regarding the [Spring gem](https://qiita.com/tak_noko/items/734c793bfc8fdc714143) and then after fixing an error regarding [Multipart post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72524985/rails-console-deprecation-notices-after-updating-gems). After lot of trial and error I decided to undo all the fixes by doing a `git reset --hard` and then removing the `spring` and `spring-watcher-listen` gems from the `Gemfile` and then uninstalling these 2 gems via the `bundle exec gem uninstall gemname` command.

I then discovered a new error when trying to run `rails s` which was about `MySQL`. Finally after fixing those errors I was able to do a successful `rails s`. I then added back the 2 gems, ran `bundle` and had no errors afterwards.