# uninitialized constant HTML::Pipeline::SanitizationFilter::WHITELIST (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I can't seem to find this specific error anywhere on this site for solutions, hope someone can please assist. This is the error I run into when I run `rails s`:

```
➜  conquered_self git:(352_space_time_empires) ✗ rails s
Top level ::CompositeIO is deprecated, require 'multipart/post' and use `Multipart::Post::CompositeReadIO` instead!
Top level ::Parts is deprecated, require 'multipart/post' and use `Multipart::Post::Parts` instead!
Traceback (most recent call last):
    31: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    30: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    29: from /Users/buddha/Documents/conquered_self/bin/spring:14:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    27: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    26: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    24: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    22: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    21: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    20: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    19: from /Users/buddha/Documents/conquered_self/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    18: from /Users/buddha/Documents/conquered_self/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    17: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    15: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    14: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    13: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    12: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    11: from /Users/buddha/Documents/conquered_self/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
     9: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
     8: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
     7: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
     6: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
     5: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
     4: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require'
     3: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thredded-0.9.4/lib/thredded.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thredded-0.9.4/lib/thredded/content_formatter.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thredded-0.9.4/lib/thredded/content_formatter.rb:4:in `<module:Thredded>'
/Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thredded-0.9.4/lib/thredded/content_formatter.rb:8:in `<class:ContentFormatter>': uninitialized constant HTML::Pipeline::SanitizationFilter::WHITELIST (NameError)
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'bitfields', "~> 0.8.0"
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta'
gem 'braintree', "~> 2.70.0"
gem 'ckeditor', "~> 4.2.4"
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2.2'
gem 'devise', "~> 4.6.2"
gem 'devise_masquerade', "~> 0.6.5"
gem 'dragonfly', "~> 1.1.3"
gem 'dragonfly-s3_data_store', "~> 1.3.0"
gem 'exception_notification', "~> 4.2.2"
gem 'execjs', "~> 2.7.0"
gem 'figaro', "~> 1.1.1"
gem 'icalendar', "~> 2.4.1"
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', "~> 4.3.1"
gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.8'
gem 'mandrill_dm'
gem 'meta-tags', "~> 2.6.0"
gem 'mysql2', "~> 0.4.9"
gem 'omniauth-facebook', "~> 5.0.0"
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', "~> 0.5.2"
gem 'phony', "~> 2.15.48"
gem 'popper_js', "~> 1.11.1"
gem 'pundit', "~> 1.1.0"
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.6'
gem 'rails_engine_decorators', git: 'https://github.com/HelloThisIsMartha/rails_engine_decorators'
gem 'react-rails', "~> 2.4.7"
gem 'redis-rails', "~> 5.0.2"
gem 'request_store', "~> 1.3.2"
gem 'rinku', "~> 2.0.3"
gem 'roman-numerals', "~> 0.3.0"
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.6'
gem 'sidekiq', "~> 5.0.4"
gem 'textris', "~> 0.4.4"
gem 'mini_racer'
gem 'thredded', '~> 0.9.4'
gem "timecop", "~> 0.9.4"
gem 'twilio-ruby', "~> 5.2.3"
gem 'uglifier', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'websocket-driver', "~> 0.6.5"
gem 'whenever', "~> 0.9.7", :require => false

# Boostrap 4 alpha requires assets tether
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '~> 1.4.0'
end

group :staging, :production, :devasprod do
  gem 'puma', '~> 3.12.6'
  gem 'puma_worker_killer', "~> 0.1.0"
end

group :staging, :production do
  gem 'newrelic_rpm', "~> 4.0.0.332"
end

group :development, :test, :staging do
  gem 'byebug', "~> 9.1.0", platform: :mri
  gem 'pry-rails', "~> 0.3.6"
  gem 'pry-byebug', "~> 3.5.0"
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.6.1'
end

group :development do
  gem 'mailcatcher', "~> 0.2.4"
  gem 'pry-rescue', "~> 1.4.5"
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer', "~> 0.4.9.2"
  gem 'rubocop-rails', "~> 2.3.2"
  gem 'spring', "~> 2.0.2"
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.1'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 3.5.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner', "~> 1.6.1"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', "~> 4.8.0"
end

group :development do
  gem 'flamegraph', "~> 0.9.5"
  gem 'memory_profiler', "~> 0.9.8"
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', "~> 0.10.5"
  gem 'stackprof', "~> 0.2.10"
end
```

Rails and Ruby versions:

```
➜  conquered_self git:(352_space_time_empires) ✗ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-darwin21]
➜  conquered_self git:(352_space_time_empires) ✗ rails -v
Rails 5.0.7.2
```

Btw, I tried the suggestions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72524985/rails-console-deprecation-notices-after-updating-gems) and added the `gem 'faraday-multipart'` to my gemfile, ran `bundle`, then `rail s` gave me a different error:

```
➜  conquered_self git:(352_space_time_empires) ✗ rails s
Traceback (most recent call last):
    15: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    14: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    13: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    11: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    10: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
     9: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
     8: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
     7: from /Users/buddha/Documents/conquered_self/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
     5: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
     4: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
     3: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
     2: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
     1: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require': cannot load such file -- faraday-multipart (LoadError)
    19: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    18: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    17: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    15: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    14: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    13: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    12: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    11: from /Users/buddha/Documents/conquered_self/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
     9: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
     8: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
     7: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `block in require'
     6: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:88:in `rescue in block in require'
     5: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:88:in `require'
     4: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/faraday-multipart-1.0.4/lib/faraday/multipart.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
     3: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/faraday-multipart-1.0.4/lib/faraday/multipart.rb:6:in `require_relative'
     2: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/faraday-multipart-1.0.4/lib/faraday/multipart/middleware.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/faraday-multipart-1.0.4/lib/faraday/multipart/middleware.rb:6:in `<module:Faraday>'
/Users/buddha/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/faraday-multipart-1.0.4/lib/faraday/multipart/middleware.rb:8:in `<module:Multipart>': uninitialized constant Faraday::Request (NameError)
```

Answer (score 1):

##### faraday / faraday-multipart:

If you didn't have these gems before, they aren't the issue and you don't need to add them.

```bash
$ gem uninstall faraday
$ gem uninstall faraday-multipart
```

Also, faraday-multipart didn't actually install (or didn't install correctly) as can be seen from the middle of the stack trace. Try `gem install faraday-multipart` or make sure it's in your gemfile and then run `bundle install` if you really want it. Also check your `Gemfile.lock` to see if `faraday` and `faraday-multipart` are there.

**But again**, you don't seem to need [faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) or [faraday-multipart](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday-multipart) at all. The SO you reference talks about updating them, not adding it to an app that doesn't have them.

##### thredded:

The issue is coming from this gem. Specifically, line 8 of [this file](https://github.com/thredded/thredded/blob/v0.9.4/lib/thredded/content_formatter.rb)

You could debug this or you could upgrade this *severely* out-of-date gem. (you're using 0.9.4 and it's currently at 0.16.16)

##### better fix:

SOOO many of your gems look to be real old and out of date. Including Ruby and Rails.

If I were you, I would first update my Ruby install to 3.1.2, then my Rails gem to at least 6.0+

Next, I would either:

1. Carefully go through each gem in the `Gemfile` and search for it on [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/) and upgrade the gems one by one.
2. (**brute force approach**) Remove all version requirements from your `Gemfile`, upgrade every gem at once with `bundle update` and see what is fixed and what is newly broken.