# Top level ::CompositeIO is deprecated, require 'multipart/post' and use `Multipart::Post::CompositeReadIO` instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am running an old project which is built in rails 3.1 and ruby-1.9.3. When I am trying to migrate my models, it is causing the following problem.

rake db:migrate ->
Top level ::CompositeIO is deprecated, require 'multipart/post' and use `Multipart::Post::CompositeReadIO` instead!
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `deprecate_constant' for Object:Class

I have searched a lot but unfortunately could not find a solution. My environment is as follows.

- Rails 3.1 ruby 1.9.3 postgres 9.6 bundler 1.17.3

Comment: The top answer on this question worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72524985/rails-console-deprecation-notices-after-updating-gems